# Bootstrap Responsive Wrappers module's Format field won't save using Drupal 8

Tags: input-formats, bootstrap-theme

I've setup a new style (Configuration / Content Authoring / Text Formats and Editors) in order to use the Bootstrap Responsive Wrappers module for video embeds.

I can apply the Format to text fields during field creation. But after saving if I edit the field again it has reverted back to "basic HTML".

Are there any alternative Modules for successfully allowing fields to responsively embed videos from Youtube within Drupal 8 using Bootstrap 4 based theme?

**UPDATE: I Found an alternate solution:**
I've started to using this module instead: 
https://www.drupal.org/project/video_embed_field

The Video Embed Field module is working responsively now and required little effort to set it up.

Comment: Potentially a bug with this module?

Comment: @Kevin yes seems to be, I've reverted to using this module instead: 

https://www.drupal.org/project/video_embed_field

and it is working and responsive with little effort to setup